# How to identify albums in "Gallery" app ? The UI automator just displays a Relative Layout without identifying the individual albums

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium, ui-automation

How to identify albums in "Gallery" app ? The UI automator just displays a Relative Layout without identifying the individual albums.

I am using Appium.
I am using a real device (Motorola X Play)

Exact functionlity : Open Whatsapp - Search a contact - Click on Attachment icon - Navigate to Gallery app (from Whatsapp ) - Select a pic from a specific album and then send to the contact.

Until Navigation to Gallery app is successful. Unable to click on a specific Album.

Any expert advice would really be helpful.